# ng-cloak not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngcloak

In my angular app, I'm displaying a pdf using `<object>` tag.

```
<object ng-cloak data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{tab.documentdata}}"
         width="100%"
         height="5000"  
         standby="Loading document...">
         Oops, you have no PDF viewer enabled
</object>
```

The `{{tab.documentdata}}` is the base64 encoded data which is the response of a server request.

**Issue**

Even after adding `ng-cloak` for the object tag. I can see http request like below.

[image]

How to restrict the request being send before replacing the angular expression.

```
data:application/pdf;base64,{{tab.documentdata}}
```

Comment: [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) just prevents the template of being displayed in un-compiled form . Probably better to use [`ngIf`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) or [`ngAttr`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation#-ngattr-for-binding-to-arbitrary-attributes) in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be like

```
<object ng-attr-data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{tab.documentdata}}"
         width="100%"
         height="5000"  
         standby="Loading document...">
         Oops, you have no PDF viewer enabled
</object>
```

Comment: "Oops, you have no PDF viewer enabled" error is thrown